# python Django TinyMCE

Tags: django, tinymce

I'm trying to add an in-page editor to a project and I came across TinyMCE a HTML editor. I've been following the tutorial on how to integrate it into my app but have been getting very confused. How to set plug-ins and edit font and stuff still remain a mystery. I'm a novice in Django so any ideas will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to be as detailed as I can be. After installing tinymce using pip

> pip install django-tinymce

You add tinymce as an installed app to your project's settings.py  as below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'tinymce',
]
```

Then you include initial configurations for your tinymce also in your settings.py

```
TINYMCE_INCLUDE_JQUERY = False
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
# TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme':'advanced',
    'plugins':'table, spellchecker, paste, searchreplace',
    'menubar':'edit',
    'toolbar':'paste,attach',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1':'bold, paste, attach, italic, underline, bullist, numlist, link, unlink, styleselect, fontsizeselect',
    'width':'100%',
    'height':'300',
    'valid_styles':'font-weight, font-style, text-decoration',
    'fontsize_default':'24pt',
}
```

This should handle your concerns of integrating tinymce into your app and adding plugins. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks @Gozie, this was the sort of thing I was looking for.